# Need to join three tables and find whats missing

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: Customers, Members, Communications

```
Customers
-------------
Customer_RecID |  First_Name | Last_Name
1              |  Bob        | Smith
2              |  James      | Jones
3              |  Chris      | Johnson


Members
--------------
Member_RecID  | First_Name | Last_Name
1             | Amy        | Kite
2             | Sara       | Macky
3             | Jill       | Brite
4             | New        | User


Communications
--------------
Communication_RecID | Customer_RecID | Member_RecID | Date
1                   | 1              | 1            | 2022-02-03 00:22:10
2                   | 1              | 2            | 2022-02-03 00:22:10
3                   | 1              | 3            | 2022-02-03 00:22:10
4                   | 2              | 1            | 2022-02-03 00:22:10
5                   | 2              | 2            | 2022-02-03 00:22:10
6                   | 2              | 3            | 2022-02-03 00:22:10
7                   | 3              | 1            | 2022-02-03 00:22:10
8                   | 3              | 2            | 2022-02-03 00:22:10
9                   | 3              | 4            | 2022-02-03 00:22:10
```

Communications holds all the times that Customer has contacted Member

What I need to find is a list of all the customers that have not contacted a member.  So in my example, how do I find out which Customers have not contacted Members?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [subqueries](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php) and the [NOT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) and [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operators.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using subqueries would be a [left join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) with a where clause:

```
SELECT Customers.Customer_RecID
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Communications ON Customers.Customer_RecID = Communications.Customer_RecID
WHERE Communications.Customer_RecID IS NULL;
```

Comment: That won't work, because there are no entires in Communications with a NULL entry.  You are missing any reference to the Members table, which might cause the NULL to show up.

Comment: Yes, it will work. With a left join, the result of the joined table will return as null if there is no match between the matching columns. The Members table is irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    cw_Contact.Contact_RecID,
    cw_Contact.Company_RecID,
    cw_Contact.First_Name,
    cw_Contact.Last_Name, 
    cw_Member.Member_RecID
FROM
    cw_Contact
    JOIN users ON users.Support_Team_Long = cw_Contact.Support_Team
    
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM notification_contacts WHERE notification_contacts.Contact_RecID = cw_Contact.Contact_Recid AND notification_contacts.Member_RecID = users.SR_Member_RecID )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).